#  nested loop in show at controller in Ruby optimization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, loops, controller, nested

```
@release = Release.find(params[:id])
@release_cycles=@release.cycles    
@release_cycles=Cycle.find_by_sql("select * from cycles where release_id=#{params[:id]}")
current_page=params[:page]?Integer(params[:page]):1
@release_cycles = @release_cycles.paginate(:page=>params[:page],:per_page=>5)
release_ics=@release.ics
puts "params[releases==]==#{params[:releases]}"

releases=params[:releases].to_i
release1=(releases>0)?Release.find(params[:releases]):nil
puts "release1==#{release1}"

@non_ics=(release1!=nil)?(release1.ics):Ic.active

@non_members=[]  

@non_ics.each do |non_ic|
  check=1
  release_ics.each do |release_ic|
    if non_ic==release_ic
      check=0
      puts "inside ics comparison if"
    end
  end
  if check==1
    puts "inside if ! in release_only"
    @non_members << non_ic
    puts "@ics==#{@non_members}"
  end   
end
```

...

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @release }
  end
end
```

The commented block of code at the end is eating up runtime like crazy (takes about 20-30 seconds to load) I think I have an idea on how to optimize this but I would like a third person thought on how to optimize the code to make it go faster

Comment: This is a really long example. Is there any way you can refactor this to be a minimal failing example that still illustrates the same behavior?

Comment: Is it actually the block that's slow, or is it that the block builds up the `@non_members` array that's later passed to a search function (that could be slow because of a missing index)? How big are `@non_ics` and `release_ics`, and can you benchmark how long that loop is taking? (even just `t0 = Time.now` at the top, and `puts "#{Time.now - t0}s"` at the bottom of the block would suffice for this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire top section of the code can be replaced by 4 lines of code:

```
@release = Release.find(params[:id])
@release_cycles = @release.cycles.paginate(:page=> params[:page].presence || 1,  
    :per_page=>5)
@non_ics= params[:releases].present? ? Release.find(params[:releases]).ics : 
     Ic.active
@non_members = @non_ics - @release.ics
```

Apart from code that can be improved you are loading all the releases in to memory and paginating the result set in ruby memory space. Which can slow your process down if you have a large number of cycles for each release.

I calculated the intersection between the two arrays in the last line using Ruby. If the array size is big I would use SQL for that.

Comment: so one way is to replace the nested code with sql call and compare it in the database?

Comment: I also get a can't find release without an ID when I try to use your code, do you know why that might be?

Comment: You will get an error if the `params[:id]` is missing OR if `params[:releases]` value is set to an invalid `id`. Both cases are critical errors which should be fixed by fixing your request parameters.